How to exclude certain extensions from GitHub Code Search
Using GitHub Advanced Code Search, I'd like to find the occurrence of the "HATEOAS" query across all programming languages
I managed to construct this search query, which I don't like
"hateoas" (NOT path:**/*.rst NOT path:**/*.adoc NOT path:**/*.asciidoc NOT path:**/*.txt NOT path:**/*.org NOT path:**/*.log) AND (NOT language:Dockerfile NOT language:Shell NOT language:Markdown NOT language:YAML NOT language:XML NOT language:JSON)

How can I simplify it with regex?

Rather than eliminating unwanted file extensions, I took another approach. I used StackOverflow's  2024 Technology Survey to identify the most popular languages. Next, I found extensions for each language, and it took time to get regex right.
A solution that worked for me looks like below, and you can test it here.
"HATEOAS" path:/\.(py|js|ts|java|cs|php|go|rs|kt)/

